# TFS Workspace on distributed VM

Tags: tfs, virtual-machine

We have an "SDK" VM that we distribute to all developers. Not ideal solution but unfortunately this is the best solution for the situation we are in. We distribute this about once a month so I am trying to make it so there is as little "setup" as possible once the dev gets it.

We are unable to change the hostname due to multiple reasons.

I need to know if there is a way I can make a Hostname / Workspace / Folder location that everyone can use without getting "Path in use" and other type errors.

I previously set it up as a SHARED workspace but this is leading to developers not using "Get Specific Version" and changes are getting lost.

I also tried doing something with SymLink folders but that was not successful.

Anyone run into this setup before? How did you get this working successfully?

Comment: Do you mean you want all developers use the same workspace which is on your VM?

Comment: the problem is I couldnt use a different or same workspace because it resided in the same computername/filepath but i got it ironed out ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I was able to "Resolve" this issue. Maybe hacky but might be helpful to someone.

I created a batch file to automatically setup the workspaces. Since the computer name is going to be the same for everyone I needed different paths for each user. I also need the actual source code in a particular folder so here is what i did very briefly.

[Configure TFS for VM](https://gist.github.com/lookitstony/431f769488c67e74413f)

1. Prompt user for their username
2. Create C:\TFS\%username%
3. Remove all cached workspaces
4. Create a new named workspace (%username%-sdk)
5. Map the needed TFS paths to needed folders
6. Remove the base $\ mapping
7. Get source code for mapped paths
8. Create a symlink from their TFS folder to C:\SDK(needed folders)
9. Launch apps from the symlink director to maintain proper mappings.

Here is the actual code if anyone needs it in the future.

```
@echo off
SET me=%~n0
SET parent=%~dp0
SET log=%TEMP%\%me%.txt
SET %ERRORLEVEL%=0

echo ============================================
echo    %me%
echo ============================================

:AdminCheck
net session >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( 
    ECHO. 
) ELSE (
    ECHO Must run as an Administrator. Exiting...
    ECHO.
    EXIT /B 1
)

:DeleteWarning
echo.
echo  WARNING! This will delete all code in C:\TFS so make sure 
echo  all of your code is committed or your code will be lost!!!
echo.
set /p accept=To continue deleting type 'y': 

if not "%accept%" == "y" exit

:StartProcess
cls
echo ============================================
echo    %me%
echo ============================================
echo.

:: get user name used to create name directory and workspace name
set /p userDir=Network Username:  

:: set script variables
set sourceBase=C:\TFS
set sourcePath=%sourceBase%\%userDir%
set sourceWidgetPath=%sourcePath%\Widgets
set sourceProviderPath=%sourcePath%\Providers

:: set TFS related variables
set tfsCollection=[TFSSERVER]
set workspaceName=%userDir%-SDK
set tfsWidgetPath=[$/TFSPATH]
set tfsProviderPath=[$/TFSPATH]

:: set symlinked destination paths
set sdkWidgetPath=C:\SDK\Widgets
set sdkProviderPath=C:\SDK\Providers

:: launch VsDevCmd so we can execute tfs commands
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"

:DeleteDirectories
echo.
echo ## Delete TFS Directory ##
del /q /s /f "%sourceBase%\*" 1>nul
for /d %%x in ("%sourceBase%\*") do @rd /s /q "%%x"

:CreateDirectory
echo.
echo ## Create TFS Directory ##
mkdir %sourcePath%
cd %sourcePath%

:SetupWorkspace
echo.
echo ## Creating TFS Workspace %workspaceName% ##

:: create workspace
tf workspaces /remove:*
tf workspace /new %workspaceName% /collection:%tfsCollection% /noprompt

:: map specific folders
tf workfold /map %tfsWidgetPath% %sourceWidgetPath% /collection:%tfsCollection% /workspace:%workspaceName%
tf workfold /map %tfsProviderPath% %sourceProviderPath% /collection:%tfsCollection% /workspace:%workspaceName%

::remove base path mapping
tf workfold /unmap $/ /collection:%tfsCollection% /workspace:%workspaceName%

:GetSourceCode
echo.
echo ## Get Latest Source Code ##
tf get %tfsWidgetPath% /recursive
tf get %tfsProviderPath% /recursive

:CreateSymLink
cls
echo.
echo ## Setup Widget and Provider SymLinks ##

:: remove target folders if exist
IF EXIST %sdkWidgetPath% RD /q /s %sdkWidgetPath%
IF EXIST %sdkProviderPath% RD /q /s %sdkProviderPath%

:: create symlinks
mklink /D %sdkWidgetPath% %sourceWidgetPath%
mklink /D %sdkProviderPath% %sourceProviderPath%

cls
echo ============================================
echo    %me% [Completed]
echo ============================================
echo.
echo Workspace Created: %workspaceName%
echo.
echo Widget Source: %sourceWidgetPath%
echo Widget Working Directory: %sdkWidgetPath%
echo.
echo Provider Source: %sourceProviderPath%
echo Provider Working Directory: %sdkProviderPath%
echo.

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose **Public workspace** in **Advanced** workspace option if you want to use a single computer for a team to collaborate on an effort.

But if you want to use the same workspace in multiple instances of Visual Studio, this usage is not supported, although Visual Studio does not block you from running multiple instances against the same workspace. Also, working this way is more likely to cause problems if you are using a local workspace.

Comment: The problem I was having with this setup is that it does not recognize changes for all users. I could change code but since I share the same workspace it looks like it is up to date for everyone. This is leading to developers getting latest, receiving no new files and then committing out dated files. We have to make a conscious effort to "Get Specific" instead of latest :/

Comment: All users use the same workspace with multiple instances of Visual Studio on server, this usage is not supported. The only way is to create everyone's own workspace.

Comment: yea that's what i was trying to avoid. stinks, so i at least wrote a batch file to do it for me. Hopefully they can just run that and leave me alone now :P My main concern was me having to go around and set everyone up every time as its time consuming.